How do I remove intermediate submodule but keep the leaf submodule?
I have three layers of Git submodules which we will call root, middle and leaf. Leaf is a submodule of middle, and middle is a submodule of root.
I wish to remove middle as a submodule and make leaf a direct submodule of root while keeping all files and directory structure:
# Before:
root <-- middle <-- leaf

# After:
root <-- leaf

# While directory structure kept both before and after:
root/middle/leaf

Following this related StackOverflow thread produces strange results:
# Remove middle submodule:
cd root
git rm --cached middle
git rm .gitmodules

rm -rf middle/.git
rm -rf middle/.gitmodules
rm -rf middle/leaf # remove leaf entirely

git add middle
git commit -m "remove middle submodule"

# Add leaf as submodule of root instead of middle:
git submodule add https://<url-to>/leaf.git middle/leaf

Error:
fatal: Pathspec 'middle/leaf' is in submodule 'middle'

I have also tried to remove leaf as a submodule of middle first, then remove middle as submodule of root, then add leaf as submodule of root. Same error.
What do I do? I'm at a loss.

The full submodule removal should include rm -rf .git/modules/<path-to-submodule>, see How do I remove a submodule?
Run rm -rf .git/modules/middle before git submodule add (or somewhere after git rm --cached middle).
